# iOS link static library from xcode command line tool

Tags: ios, xcode5, static-libraries

I have a scenario in which i have to add a static library to my xcode project using shell script . I have static library with me which contains a libSomething.a file and two .h file which is to be included in the project to work . I have to link my xcode project with libSomething.a . Any help is highly appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: That won't be easy using a shell script.  Why can't you add it using the Xcode user interface?

Comment: Use Xcodeproject gem to modify the project file and add needed linkage with header copy in your Xcode project: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj